# Xcode ARC conversion tool hangs at the last compiled file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, clang

I am converting one of my big non-ARC projects to ARC (around 500 source files).
When compiling, it gives me errors list to correct, etc.. but it always hangs at the last file (Compiling 546 of 545 source files):

[image]
[image]

I see clang process taking 100% from 2 of my CPU cores so clearly it does something. Xcode (4.6.3) is responsive but result of compilation is never reached.
I have already corrected all errors required by compiler to convert to ARC so it looks like it hangs at the very last step of the process.

What can cause this hang? Size of the project? Or isn't it really hang but conversion takes so long for this amount of source files? IS there something I should do or just wait? I see it already took around 15 minutes.

After pressing stop (accidentally) conversion tool went to the 'Generating Preview' stage and hanged there on 'Compiling 437 out of 546 file':

[image]

Comment: You have indexing processing in the same time - maybe that's the reason. Try cleaning up whole project (Project / Clean) remove derived data from organizer and try again after indexing is completed. If it doesn't help try searching for some header import loops.

Comment: Tried it (Cleaned project, removed Derived Data, did wait until indexing finishes), still the same. that mght be issue of circular imports then. But why wasn't this an issue before (for non-arc compiler)?

Comment: Problem is gone with Xcode 5 GM